# Is there anything like attacks of opportunity in L5R 4e?

Tags: opportunity-attack, l5r-4e

Are there any sort of rules about attack of opportunity or the like in L5R? If there are none, does it mean that an archer can uses his free actions to move back and then shoot the guy that just attacked him in melee and repeat the process the next turn?

Comment: Just to clarify further, is this being asked in the context of coming from a background in a different game that does have Attacks of Opportunity?

Comment: Yeah, I usually play D&D 3.5 then thought about the attacks of opportunity that it has and that seemed to not exist in L5R 4e. I thought that there would be no problem being an archer in l5R even if I'm being forced in melee combat. I found this strange so I came here to ask.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The majority of my knowledge of L5R comes from 4th edition and I'm almost positive it does not have AoOs at least in the D&D sense of the term (barring some obscure Technique or Kata that I'm forgetting). It's a society of honourable warriors, few would offer such an opportunity and none would stoop so low as to take it (except the Scorpion or Spider clan, but even they wouldn't if anyone was watching)

As to kiting with an archer: yes, it is possible but very few can pull it off. To keep out of range of a melee character you will have to be making at least a simple action movement every turn. Only 2-3 techniques give you a simple action attack with a bow that would allow you to follow that movement up with shot. even then a melee character can take a Full Attack Stance and charge you to keep up so at most this just prevents the melee character from taking 2 attacks per turn on you.

You would probably be considered an honourless coward for employing this technique however. You hold you grandfather's sword at your hip, why do you hesitate to use it? (gain infamy and/or lose glory if you manage to survive.)

Comment: That said, I believe 2nd edition was D&D 3.0 compatible and would probably have to include AoO rules...

Comment: L5R 2nd edition was a normal L5R edition and wasn't D&D 3.0 compatible. You might be thinking of WotC's line of *Rokugan* dual-statted D&D 3e/L5R books that were published in the short time that WotC owned the Rokugan setting.

Comment: "Oriental Adventures" was the d20 compatible title.  Also, Honor isn't a 100% exclusively held trait.  A Daidoji Harrier might pull off a stunt like this using terrain well, or maybe a Shosuro Shinobi as examples

Comment: for ref: According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legend_of_the_Five_Rings_Roleplaying_Game#Second_Edition) All the L5R 2e splats, bar 3,  were duel statted. as @SevenSidedDie said.

*"Second Edition, with the exception of the Player's Guide, Game Master's Guide, Way of the Shadowlands, Winter Court: Kyuden Asako, and Time of the Void, books published for the Legend of the Five Rings RPG had two different sets of game mechanics: the mechanics from the ...  Second Edition Player's Guide and corresponding mechanics for d20 System, such as those presented in Oriental Adventures"*

Comment: Since there's clearly a lot to say on the subject, but the status of L5R's system compatibility is rather off topic for this Q&A, I started a question to be home to these clarifications: [Was L5R 2nd Edition based on or compatible with D&D 3.0?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/87145) CatLord and Oxinabox, take a look in case you wish to write fuller answers! Saelvarath, thanks for prompting the question.

Comment: Depending on GM rulings regarding what's required to issue movement commands to a horse, most Unicorn could perform quite well as cavalry archers at Rank 1. And as there's nothing dishonorable about using ranged weapons, there should equally be nothing dishonorable about maintaining distance to use ranged weapons. If someone is stupid enough to fall for it or not bring ranged weapons of their own to the battle... well, choosing not to take advantage of it would be an act of sincere courtesy to an enemy (Honor gain).