# Which books are in AEG's Oriental Adventures product line?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dnd-3e, product-identification, books

Which books are in AEG's Oriental Adventures product line?

The books in that line are the ones that WotC gave permission to use [this logo](https://www.tsrarchive.com/3o/3o-logo.gif).

Comment: The post body should contain the primary question, along with any necessary additional details. I've edited the body to match the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Oriental Adventures

Alderac Entertainment Group (AEG; Web site [here](https://www.alderac.com/) and Wiki entry [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alderac_Entertainment_Group)) published the entirety of the Oriental Adventures line save for [*Oriental Adventures*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oriental_Adventures#Dungeons_&_Dragons_3rd_edition) proper that was published by Wizards of the Coast.

- 2001/10 *Rokugan*
- 2002/01 *Magic of Rokugan*
- 2002/03 *Creatures of Rokugan*
- 2002/03 *Way of the Samurai*
- 2002/05 *Way of the Ninja*
- 2002/07 *Way of the Shugenja*
- 2002/08 *Fortunes and Winds*
- 2002/10 *Secrets of the Lion*
- 2002/12 *Secrets of the Mantis*
- 2003/02 *Secrets of the Phoenix*
- 2003/04 *Secrets of the Scorpion*
- 2003/06 *Secrets of the Crab*
- 2003/08 *Secrets of the Crane*
- 2003/10 *Secrets of the Unicorn*
- 2003/12 *Bloodspeakers*<sup>1</sup>
- 2003/12 *Secrets of the Dragon*
- 2003/02 *Secrets of the Shadowlands*
- 2004/04 *Complete Exotic Arms Guide*
- 2004/06 *Way of the Open Hand*
- 2004/10 *Way of the Daimyo*
- 2004/12 *Way of the Thief*
- 2005/09 *The Hidden Emperor*

These books largely concern in and around [Rokugan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rokugan), the setting that's used for AEG's *Legend of the Five Rings* properties. Some of these books go so far as to include—in addition to *Dungeons & Dragons, Third Edition* rules—rules for the same things for the second edition of the [*Legend of the Five Rings*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legend_of_the_Five_Rings_Roleplaying_Game#Second_Edition_(AEG)) role-playing game. (Also see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/87145/8610). Also omitted from this list is other *Legend of the Five Rings, Second Edition* material—not my thing.) The prospective reader should take note: These books are not, for example, generic resources for this setting nor do they expand on other *Oriental Adventures* campaign settings, like [Mahasarpa](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/we/20011019a).

Also—and holy crap!—, look at that publishing schedule! That's a new 128-page sourcebook almost *every other month!* During the [d20 boom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D20_System#2000%E2%80%932003:_d20_boom), too many books were published too quickly and—almost inevitably—quality suffered. These books are no exception, and it may be to your benefit to show a little grammatical forgiveness as you go. These folks' deadlines were *tight.*

---

<sup>**1**</sup> *Bloodspeakers* is an unusual case. Copyright information concludes with this: "*Bloodspeakers* in produces [*sic*] by Paradigm Concepts, Inc. under license from AEG." However, the copyright information begins with this: Legend of the Five Rings is produced under license from Wizards of the Coast…." No further AEG material was (co-?)published for the Oriental Adventures line by Paradigm afterward, so there's nothing to compare it to. Thus I've never been clear if *Bloodspeakers* were officially an "official" product or not. I mean, at this point, who cares, right? The '*Speakers*'s got some crazy in it, but unless you're intent on breaking the game with its modified Taint rules, there's no more going *against* it that isn't true of the entire line.