# Feat that allows sleeping in heavy armor without becoming fatigued?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, sleep

I was shocked to discover today that Endurance **doesn’t** do this:

> **Benefit:** […] you may sleep in **light or medium** armor without becoming fatigued.

> **Normal:** A character without this feat who sleeps in **medium or heavier** armor is automatically fatigued the next day.

(Nevermind the fact that light armor doesn’t fatigue *anyone*...)

So is there a feat for this? It has to be specifically a feat for my purposes; I know a *restful crystal* can do it, and I’m sure there are others, but a feat is what I’m looking for.

I am also looking specifically for a feat that says “you may sleep in heavy armor without becoming fatigued.” Things that effectively cause that to happen one way or the other are not what I’m interested in. So, for example, if there was a feat that caused heavy armor to be treated as medium armor, which combined with Endurance allows you to sleep in the formerly-heavy armor without getting fatigued, that would **not** be an answer to this question. Nor would a feat that allows you to not sleep, or makes you immune to fatigue. Just looking for a feat with this specific benefit. (The feat may certainly have *other* benefits as well, but this one has to be an explicit benefit written into the feat.)

Any WotC-published 3.5e material, or *Dragon* or *Dungeon* 3.5e material, including 3.5e-legal 3.0e material, is valid for this question.

Comment: This feels a lot like an X/Y problem, though your posting history suggests you've got a good reason for the level of specificity in the question. Out of curiosity, then, why does this need to be a feat with this level of specificity?

Comment: @minnmass Because if the feat exists, I want to add it to the bonus feat list for my heavy-armor-focused class. If it doesn’t exist, I may not bother, I may homebrew up a feat to add to the list, but first, I want to know if there’s an official version. Also, at this point, pure curiosity, since I was shocked that it wasn’t already part of Endurance and surprised not to quickly find “Improved Endurance” or “Heavy Armor Endurance” or something in _Complete Warrior_ or find the feature as part of Heavy Armor Optimization in _Races of Stone_ or something.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## There's no feat for this

So far as I'm aware, no official or officially licensed feat—explicitly as one of its benefits—allows a typical creature to sleep in heavy armor yet avoid being fatigued upon awakening. Wizards of the Coast never published such a feat, and no such feat exists in any licensed product. No feat even hints at the possibility.

(So readers understand the depth of this search, I searched separately for *heavy armor* then for *sleep* in my 2,500-page document that I compiled that includes—so far as I'm aware—all of the over 7,500 feats for *Dungeons & Dragons, Third Edition* (inclusive) published by Wizards of the Coast and published in products officially licensed by Wizards of the Coast—in both treeware and electronic formats. And I came up empty. (Honestly, with Rokugan's Crab clan's reliance on heavy armor, I thought that the [Oriental Adventures](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/158958/8610) line would yield results but no luck.) To be clear, the document doesn't include feats published by third parties, which are beyond this question's scope.)

- **Magic Options You Don't Want:** A ***potion of lesser restoration*** [conj] (*Player's Handbook* 272) (50 gp when created by a paladin; 0.1 lbs.) removes fatigue, including the fatigue caused by sleeping in heavy armor. But, really, you're right that folks who find themselves sleeping in heavy armor regularly want a ***restful crystal*** (*Magic Item Compendium* 26) (500 gp; 0 lbs.). Monied folks may don their heavy armor using the magic armor special ability ***called*** (*MIC* 9) (+2,000 gp; 0 lbs.) or a ***ring of arming*** (*MIC* 122) (5,000 gp; 0 lbs.), but, since those take actions to employ, a *restful crystal* often remains the best option even at high levels.
- **A Feat No One Takes:** If you want an [ivory tower](http://web.archive.org/web/20080221174425/http://www.montecook.com/cgi-bin/page.cgi?mc_los_142) feat to include in a list of bonus feats for an armor-focused class, I have a fondness for the untyped feat **Fast Armor** (*Dragon* #284 123). Its benefit allows a creature to take 5 rounds to—alone without aid—don or remove *any* armor. Since donning armor can take up to several minutes, it's an amazing feat—except that in this ambush game 5 rounds means you're dead way before your armor's donned and that a *restful crystal* renders the feat obsolete early on in most campaigns.

---

***Note:** Proving that a game element doesn't exist is fraught with difficulty. With that in mind, I am happy to remove this answer upon another answer documenting a feat that I overlooked that, in fact, explicitly* does *have the benefit that the question wants.*

Comment: Asking this question elsewhere clued me in to the *restful* armor property in _Dungeonscape_: same 500-gp cost as the *restful crystal*, but saves the crystal slot for another (I’m fond of the *least crystal of adaptation*, myself).

Comment: @KRyan I've had PCs in my campaigns use the *restful crystal* their whole careers so that they didn't have to spend the 500 gp on the magic armor special ability *restful* for each new armor. The only time you're putting the *restful crystal* on your armor is when you're going to sleep anyway, so you just swap it out in the morning. Also, if it matters, someone else can use the *crystal* while you're on night watch. It's no *handy haversack* or *healing belt*, but it's still usually an early-on purchase.